# What does specifying the type in an RSpec actually affect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have never been sure what the difference between these options are

```
RSpec.describe V2::DirectMessagesController, type: :controller
```

vs

```
RSpec.describe V2::DirectMessagesController, type: :request
```

Or where to even look to figure it out

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are designed to drive behavior through the full stack, including routing
(provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).

A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test
`(ActionController::TestCase::Behavior)`.
It allows you to simulate a single http request in each example, and then
specify expected outcomes such as:

- rendered templates
- redirects
- instance variables assigned in the
  controller to be shared with the view
- cookies sent back with the
  response

Controller spec docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Request spec docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec